# Graphing a Piecewise Function

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, piecewise-continuity

[image]

I graphed this function below. I want to make sure I am graphing piecewise functions such as this one correctly.

[image]

Comment: yes.  it is correct.

Comment: i wonder why did someone downvote this... perfectly reasonable to ask a question with own solution posted...

Comment: Your graph is fine. You can also omit the circles (excluding / including point) at $x=1$ since the function is continuous there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check your functions yourself, try [wolfram-alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29%3DPiecewise%5B%7B%7Bx+%2B2+%2Cx+%3C%3D+-2+%7D%2C+%7Bx%5E2%2C+-2%3Cx%3C1+%7D%2C+%7B-x%2B2%2C+x%3E%3D+1%7D%7D%5D)

It is quite not pretty to plot a piecewise function there, but it is possible.

$$f(x)=Piecewise[{{x +2 ,x <= -2 }, {x^2, -2<x<1 }, {-x+2, x>= 1}}]$$

Unfortunately the circles are missing, but you already drew them right.